# Listen to all incoming traffic in firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Is there a way to listen to ALL incoming traffic using the extensions api?
I tried using the I tried using an observer listening to 'http-on-examine-response' but the browser get stuck whenever I launch this

Help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to use Firefox addon-sdk, the official document have an example

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/system/events.html